# How do I correctly use an iteration value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, iteration

I am creating a 'simple' javaScript function which basically displays new information on the page when a user clicks next or previous.
The information is taken from an array and I want to use either i++ or i-- to call an element of the array.

Heres my JavaScript:

```
var titles = ["Dundalk", "Navan", "Drogheda", "Dublin"];
var i = 0;

function next()
    {
    i++;
    if (i == titles.length)
        {
        i = 0;
        }
    var object = document.getElementById('tname');
    object.innerHTML = titles[i];
    }

function prev()
    {
    if (i == 0)
        {
        i = titles.length;
        }
    i--;
    var object = document.getElementById('tname');
    object.innerHTML = titles[i];
    }
```

The problem is, when I run this code in my HTML page, I get an 'UNDEFINED' result.  The JavaScript is not recognizing that i has been initialized as 0 in the beginning.
If i change titles[i] to titles[2], for example, the correct text is displayed in HTML.

What am I forgetting or how can I overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're seeing `undefined` indicates that you're accessing an array index which hasn't been set. Your code looks fine at a glance, so I would guess that there's some more code you're not showing which *also* uses `i` as a loop variable and leaves it set to a value `> titles.length` after the code above has run.

Comment: Indeed. A common "mistake" is to do `for (i=0;i<n;i++){...}` which will overwrite the global `i`... @OP: try changing the name of `i` to something else, or wrap the code in its own function/scope.

Comment: The above JavaScript is complete.  However I use other JavaScript not compiled by me which must also be using the i value because when I changed this to position=0; it worked fine! Thanks guys!